# How to prevent iPhone SE from always uploading burst photos?

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream, iphone, camera

I have turned OFF the "Upload Burst Photos" option in both Camera and iCloud settings, but they are still always uploaded to my Photo Stream.  I absolutely do not want such photos to upload automatically, I want to always have to manually upload anything that was originally captured in burst mode.

Why is my phone always uploading burst photos regardless of having the setting disabled?  How can I stop this?

Comment: A relaunch of the camera app, and a reboot have both done nothing to change this situation.  All burst photos are being instantly uploaded to my Photo Stream.  This is incredibly annoying, does nobody have any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: Make sure you are not favoriting every burst, as that would cause them to upload too. And to confirm, you have unchecked "Upload Burst Photos" in Photos and Camera settings? Please comment back @JohnRamos and I can help you further.

Comment: Yes I have unchecked both, and I am not favoriting anything.  The photos are uploaded immediately after taking them, I don't even have to have looked at them or anything.  They are just immediately posted to Photo Stream, about 10 to 20 seconds after I take them.

Comment: Hmm. I'll keep digging but this really sounds like a bug to me. Maybe turn off and back on (in Photos and Camera settings) iCloud Photo Library, Upload to My Photo Stream, and iCloud Photo Sharing. Or chat with apple support at www.getsupport.apple.com

Comment: Yeah I have tried turning things off & on again, rebooting, etc.  No change.  Guess I could try Apple support, my previous experiences with them have been that they really have absolutely no clue what their customers are doing or asking about.  But maybe I'll get lucky this time.

Comment: Are all your bursts successfully collecting in a "Bursts" automatic smart album in your Photos app?

Comment: Yes they are...

Comment: So that means it's not a problem with identifying the bursts. Hmmm. Are you using iCloud Photo Library or just Photo Stream (you can find out in Photos and Camera settings)?

Comment: No iCloud Photo Library as my other devices don't support it.  Just Photo Stream.

Comment: Then I really don't know what to say. Call apple, I guess.

Comment: Yeah that's where I'm at now.  Going to try them over the weekend I guess.

Comment: You know what, I can try to keep helping :). Did this issue correspond with a software update? Does turning on/off Live Photos, HDR, or (in Photos and Camera settings) "keep original HDR photo" change anything?

Comment: And you're taking the photos in the default camera app, correct?

Comment: Also try disabling all of your apps' access to both camera and photos; they might be re-saving photos or altering metadata in some destructive way.

Comment: Thanks for trying!  Not sure about software update, this phone came with iOS9.3 on it and I didn't notice this issue until after I had updated to 9.3.1.  Default camera app - yes.  Turning on/off HDR or Live Photos - no change.  Keep Original HDR - no change.  Disabling apps access (only 2 apps had access to the camera) - no change.  One interesting thing though, if I delete the burst photos from my Camera Roll they are also automatically deleted from Photo Stream!  I did not expect that.

Comment: If you delete a normal photo, does it disappear from your photo stream? Also, what are the negatives (space, I guess?) with having bursts in your photo stream? And to confirm, you also disallowed apps access to your photos (not just your camera)?

Comment: Delete normal photo and it also deletes from Photo Stream.  I only disabled access to apps, not to the camera itself (can you even disallow access to Photos from your camera?? That seems weird).  My use of Burst Photos is so that I can take certain secure photos that I never want to touch the network.  Burst mode would in theory let me do this.  Normal photos would go to the cloud like I want, Burst Photos would not.  I could strip them down to the single photo I actually want and store them securely off my device, with no concerns that they ever left my local possession.

Comment: You're right that you can't disallow the camera access to your photos, I just wanted to make sure you disallowed all apps' access to your photos, which it sounds like you did. I think your issue is a bug with iOS, so I really don't think I can fix that, but I can offer you a workaround. Take photos with an app like this one: https://appsto.re/us/kfiA1.i and just don't let it access your photos; you'll have the secure photo taking function I think you want.

Comment: Thanks, if Apple support can't come up with a real solution, then using another app is probably my only choice.  Appreciate all your suggestions!

Comment: Sadly, Photorange appears to not allow ANY sharing of the photos it takes, with the built-in photo library.  I don't want to preclude ever being able to upload photos to my PhotoStream, I just don't want it to be automatic with certain photos.  It's looking more and more like I'm just out of luck, but I will still try Apple Support next week.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe this app? I'm kind of out of ideas here :(. Keep Safe Private Photo Vault & Picture Locker https://appsto.re/us/H-0CE.i

Comment: I'll check it out, you're a star for continuing to try and help.  Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, you're welcome :). Good luck finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after an hour on the phone with Apple support, 2 phone restores and 1 iOS upgrade, we finally got to the bottom of this.  Turns out the feature (to disable uploading of burst photos to PhotoStream) DOES work as intended.  It's the wording of the feature description that is more than a little confusing.

The text below the feature states:

> Only favorite Burst Photos will be uploaded to your Photo Stream

The trouble is, to me (and to the techs at Apple that I spoke to), that sounds like no part of a burst photo will be uploaded until you have chosen one of the photos in the burst, as a favorite.  This is not so.  What it actually means is that the *entire burst* will not be uploaded.  But if you have Photo Stream turned on, a single photo from the burst WILL be uploaded.  And unfortunately, it's not the first frame.  I'm actually not sure what criteria iOS uses to decide which photo to upload, but it seems to be the first photo that it thinks is "the best" somehow.

So, the bottom line is that Photo Stream is an all-or-nothing proposition.  Either every photo you take (including a single frame from any burst photos) will be uploaded, or nothing will be uploaded.  There is no way to selectively upload photos on a case-by-case basis, unless you either leave Photo Stream off and manually share photos you want in your stream every time, or turn Photo Stream off & on between each photo you don't want to upload... but then you lose and have to re-download all your photostream content each time.  Not a real great solution either way.

I feel Apple should re-word the description of this feature to make it more clear what the expected behavior actually is, but I won't hold my breath on that.